# Current solution contains incorrect configurations mapping using Premake5 with C#

Tags: c#, c++, building, premake

I'm trying to develop an engine and I was looking for a GUI library in C# in order to build the editor for my engine. I found **Avalonia** but I'm having some problems setting up the whole environment.

I'm using **Premake5** as build tool mixing **C++** and **C#** but I think the problem here is not the languages mixing.

[image]

I'm getting this error when I generate my visual studio solution file. Sorry about the image, I needed to post it that way cause when I press the **"Open Configuration Manager"** the error is gone and exit the Configuration Manager window the compilation works as expected, quite weird.

Here's my code:
This is the premake5 script I run:

```
include "Dependencies.lua"

workspace "LeafEngine"
    startproject "LeafEditor"

    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    platforms { "x64" }
    flags { "MultiProcessorCompile" }
    
    outputdir = "%{cfg.buildcfg}-%{cfg.system}-%{cfg.platform}"

group "Dependencies"
    include "Leaf/vendor/glfw"
    include "Leaf/vendor/imgui"
group ""

include "Leaf"
include "LeafEditor"
include "LeafGame"
```

Leaf is my C++ engine and LeafGame just a C++ test. Leaf editor is the C# project, which looks like this:

```
project "LeafEditor"
    kind "WindowedApp"
    language "C#"
    clr "On"

    targetdir   ("%{wks.location}/bin/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")
    objdir      ("%{wks.location}/bin-obj/" .. outputdir .. "/%{prj.name}")

    dotnetframework "net6.0"

    nuget { "Avalonia:0.10.13", "Avalonia.Desktop:0.10.13",
            "Avalonia.Diagnostics:0.10.13", "Avalonia.ReactiveUI:0.10.13",
            "XamlNameReferenceGenerator:1.3.4"
          }

    files
    {
        "src/**.cs",
        "src/**.xaml",
        "src/**.xaml.cs",
    }

    links
    {
        "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers",
        "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers",
        "System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration",
        "Microsoft.NETCore.APP",
    }

filter "system:Windows"
    defines "LF_WINDOWS"
    
filter "system:Unix"
    defines "LF_LINUX"

filter "configurations:Debug"
    defines "LF_DEBUG"
    runtime "Debug"
    symbols "on"

filter "configurations:Release"
    defines "LF_RELEASE"
    runtime "Release"
    optimize "full"
```

Another curious thing about Avalonia: as you can see I only have one available platform **("x64")** for building. Well, Avalonia compiles with **("Any CPU")** platform and that also breaks my whole building set up. Besides, Avalonia gets compiled with Any CPU when I load the project not when I compile the project, is that right?

Thanks in advance, this error is killling me.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, both when my C# project was built with premake and with it as an external project.

The solution (granted I gave up on premake for C# so this may only apply to externalproject) is to not add `architecture` or any specific `platform` to your workspace, and instead add it to all but your C# project. I would leave a comment since this *might* not be the answer you're looking for, but I don't have enough reputation. Anyway, for example,

```
    workspace "Lotus"
    startproject "LotusEditor"

    configurations
    {
        "Debug",
        "Release"
    }
project "CppProject"
architecture "x86_64" -- sets CppProject as x64 but not the workspace
-- more project config

externalproject "CsProject" -- no architecture/platform set for this. Might work for non externalprojects too
location "path"
uuid "insert uuid"
kind "WindowedApp"
language "C#"
```

Even with my project made manually not with premake, and set with target platform as x64, it still seems to want "Any CPU" as the configuration, which premake can't do.